# How to create http-equiv="content-language" using metamagic?

Tags: ruby

I am using [metamagic](https://github.com/lassebunk/metamagic) for meta tags. I want to generate the following line:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en" />
```

using metamagic. How can I create this?

I added the gem files and it is working, and for:

```
<% meta owner: "XYZ" %>
```

I get the result:

```
<meta name='owner' content="XYZ"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given its [source code](https://github.com/lassebunk/metamagic/blob/master/lib/metamagic/tags/meta_tag.rb), it is not possible.

You can just use `tag` instead:

```
tag 'meta', 'http-equiv' => 'content-language', 'content' => 'en'
```

Comment: <%= tag 'meta', 'http-equiv' => 'content-language', 'content' => 'en' %>